# Nonexistence of a holomorphic function with very small values at $1/n$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

I am trying to solve the following problem using the maximum modulus principle:

I have a complex function $f$, analytic on an open and connected set $U$ containing $z = 0$, and I know that $|f(1/n)| < 1/2^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. I want to prove that this function is constant (and equal to zero) on $U$. Now I know that, by the maximum modulus principle, it would be sufficient to show that $|f(z)|$ attains a maximum on $U$ (it is not hard to show that $f(0) = 0$, so it then follows that $f = 0$ everywhere on $U$). However, I am not sure how to show this, and I am not even sure that this is the right way to do it. Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Suggestion: Expand $f$ is a power series at $0$, and let $a_{m}z^{m}$ be the lowest-degree non-zero term. What can you say about the asymptotic behavior of $f(1/n)$ in terms of $m$?

Comment: I already tried expanding $f$, since $f(0) = 0$ I also know that $m > 0$. But to be honest, this is precisely the part where I got stuck...

Comment: It may help to note that you can write $f(z) = a_{m} z^{m}(1 + g(z))$ for some analytic function $g$ with $g(0) = 0$; consequently, you have a lower bound of the type $|f(z)| > \frac{1}{2}|a_{m}| \cdot |z|^{m}$ in a sufficiently small disk about $0$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm guessing that the conclusion should be that $a_m$ is equal to zero, implying that all the terms in the power series expansion are zero, hence $f = 0$ everywhere on $U$ (this must be the case). However, I still do not see how this follows from the inequality above (although I do understand where the inequality comes from). Sorry for being a bit slow, I hope you can explain your argument a bit more. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The strategy is a contrapositive argument: If there is a non-zero term in the power series, then "$|f(1/n)| < 1/2^{n}$ for all $n$" is false. You're doing great (and are almost there). :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I tried taking the limit for $n \to \infty$ in both inequalities ($|f(1/n)| > \frac{1}{2} |a_m| \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^m$ and $|f(1/n)| < 1/2^n$), but of course they both go to zero, so this does not produce a contradiction. I am now trying to find a counterexample of the inequality $ \frac{1}{2} |a_m| \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^m < 1/2^n$, is that a good strategy, and do you have a hint how to find such a counterexample? Thanks again for all your help! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59078/discussion-between-jana-and-andrew-d-hwang).

Answer (score 3):

The maximum principle is not helpful here, because the information given concerns only one point $0$: it is a *local* issue. Locally, all we need to know about a holomorphic function is encoded in its power series
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k
$$ 
The goal is to show $c_k=0$ for all $k$. Suppose this is not so. Let $m$ be the smallest index such that $c_m\ne 0$. Then 
$$
\frac{f(z)}{z^m} = \sum_{k=m}^\infty c_k z^{k-m} \to c_m \quad \text{as }  z\to 0
$$ 
In particular, plugging $z=1/n$ here yields $f(1/n) n^m\to c_m$. But this contradicts the condition given, according to which $|f(1/n)|n^m < 2^{-n} n^m \to 0$.